# How Can I post or Pin a Photo to my existing pinterest board?

Tags: php, curl, pinterest

I have fetched my existing bords on pinterst and got the information like Board Id,Board Name and Board URL.
However I want to post a Picture with Link and Description CURL code gives
me error "Authorization failed"

my code is:

```
$url_pin = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?board=' . $userName . '/' . $board_name . '&amp;note=' . $post['scheduled_text_message'] . '&link=' . $link . '&image_url=https://www.postsharing.com/img/PostSharing.png';

$ch_pin = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch_pin, CURLOPT_URL, $url_pin);

curl_setopt($ch_pin, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch_pin, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_pin = curl_exec($ch_pin);

curl_close($ch_pin);

$decoded_pin = json_decode($server_pin, true);
```

---

i am getting json_decoded result like this:-

```
Array

(

[status] => failure

[code] => 3

[host] => devplatform-devapi-prod-3c889f83

[generated_at] => Mon, 28 Dec 2015 09:04:02 +0000

[message] => Authorization failed.

[data] => 

)
```

Please anyone help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You can only create a Pin for the user corresponding to the access token. The token should either be added as the Authorization header, or in a query parameter (access_token=<the_token>)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cobble something to a board w/o valid authentication. And, userid and password aren't sufficient at all.

You need to register your App, with which you want to post to your board, at Pinterest Developers at https://developers.pinterest.com/apps/

Having an App key and secret, you may then get yourself an oAuth access token, read http://oauth.net/ or https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/

Once having a valid oAuth token, add this to your URL above:

```
$url_pin = 'https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?board=' . $userName . '/' . $board_name . '&amp;note=' . $post['scheduled_text_message'] . '&link=' . $link . '&image_url=https://www.postsharing.com/img/PostSharing.png&access_token=' + $token;
```